# Automatically assign posts with custom field to taxonomy term

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

I hope someone can help me.

- I have a custom post type called Site members with slug `site-members`
- I have a custom field (which is a select field) called `aab-ew-select-visible` and in this field users can select either of the options `display` or `hide`
- The taxonomy slug is `test-all-members-cpt-tax`
- The term slug is `test-all-members-ew-tax`

Whenever anyone posts a new post to this custom post type, they can choose to either 'hide' or 'display' a section of their post on the website. If they choose to 'display' with the select field, then they should automatically be assigned to the taxonomy term 'test-all-members-ew-tax' mentioned above.

If anyone can help with the code for this, that would be massively appreciated.

Thank you for your time,
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

The following should do what you need:

```
add_action ('save_post_site-members', 'add_term') ;

function
add_term ($post_id)
{
    if (defined ('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return ;
        }

    $meta_key = 'aab-ew-select-visible' ;
    $tax = 'test-all-members-cpt-tax' ;
    $term_slug = 'test-all-members-ew-tax' ;

    $meta_value = isset ($_REQUEST[$meta_key]) ? $_REQUEST[$meta_key] : '' ;
    if ('display' == $meta_value) {
        $term = get_term_by ('slug', $term_slug, $tax) ;
        if ($term) {
            wp_set_object_terms ($post_id, $term->term_id, $tax, true) ;
            }
        }

    return ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Paul - but for some reason that hasn't worked either. I just created a new post, selected 'display' as the value of the field, and the term wasn't assigned on saving the post. Do you know anywhere I could be going wrong? I really appreciate your time - thank you.

Comment: I just edited my answer, with a more direct way of setting $meta_value.  The original code assumed that you had some other func that hooked into `save_post-site-members` that was storing the meta...and if the func I wrote was being called before that other func then it wouldn't work.  The revised code should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for updating the code. I just ran it again, then created a new post, and still it didn't work. *Feel cursed*

Comment: I've tested (both versions of) my code and it works in a test env I have.  So, seeing a little bit more of your code would be helpful in figuring out why it's not working for you.

Comment: You might also try writing `$meta_value` & `$term` to a log file so that you can see what their values are when the `save_post` action is fired (i.e., maybe that term doesn't actually exist).

Comment: Hi @Paul - thanks again for getting back to me. Which code is it I could show you?

I'm not sure how I would write those things to a log file, sorry?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53865/discussion-between-paul-sparrow-hawk-biron-and-andrew-brown).